# How to set the text of a Button using getResources() in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to identify a button using getResources() and getIdentifier(), then set the text for it. The below code shows how I thought it should work (simply setting the ID and setting the text for the object).

```
while (c < 65) {
    val resID = getResources().getIdentifier("S1", "id", getPackageName())
    resID.text = ""
}
```

Instead I get an error, with ".text" showing red. How should I go about setting this up to run how I expected.

Comment: That's because resID is an integer. Ints don't have a variable called `text`. You'll need to grad a `View` with the ID, and I highly recommend you store it instead of finding it 65 times

Comment: Resource id is an integer value. It represents the Resource saved somewhere in your res directory. To change the text for the button you will need to find the view of the button by using findViewById(). then you can set the text to it.

Answer (score 1):

`resID` is the integer id of a `Button` "named" `S1`.  
Use it to find the `Button`:

```
val resID = resources.getIdentifier("S1", "id", getPackageName())
val button = findViewById<Button>(resID)
button.text = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

based on [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) getIdentifier returns Int , so you need `findViewById` and use the getIdentifier result in order to use the object

Answer (score -1):

**Kotlin Extensions do not work if the referenced int is not coming from** `R.id`.

1. **Button** is a view, then you can access to it by using 
   `findViewById<Button>(buttonId)`
2. If you want to retrieve id from resources, just `getResources().getIdentifier("S1", "id", getPackageName())`

In conclusion, you see how this is going to be:

```
val buttonId = getResources().getIdentifier("S1", "id", getPackageName())
val button = findViewById<Button>(buttonId)
button.setText("")
```